Create overloaded functions ignoring irrelevant parameters in the signature
How can I change the signature of the overloads to signal to type checkers that only a single parameter is responsible for the return type, ignoring all the other parameters?
Starting from this code (neither mypy nor pyright complains yet):
from typing import Literal, overload

@overload
def test(switch: Literal[True]) -> int: ...
@overload
def test(switch: Literal[False]) -> None: ...

def test(switch: bool) -> int | None:
    return 123 if switch is True else None

test_int: int = test(True)
test_none: None = test(False)

Now I want to add parameters (perspectively a lot!) that are irrelevant to the return type:
def test(switch: bool, var1: str, var2: float, var3: int) -> int | None:
    return 123 if switch is True else None

How can I change the overloads, so that I don't have to update them everytime I add another parameter? I tried with *args and **kwargs combined with Any in the overloads, but haven't been successful.

If simplicity and flexibility are more important than full typing of all parameters, the **kwargs solution may be optimal. If you need strict typing and are willing to complicate your code a bit, the Protocol or TypedDict approach may be a better choice. If you want to keep the usual style of function calls and still have full type information, the Callable approach may be preferable.

Not sure what the question is. Are you saying that you want to add a new (optional?) parameter, but now your type checker thinks that the return type of test(True, '') is int | None rather than the desired int?

@Dunes: This is a minimal example. In field I already have 24 additional parameter to switch. None of them changes the return type. Only switch does.

@sLoNcE: I experimented with **kwargs, but was not able to get it to work.
Can you provide a working example for any of your suggestions?

If the 3 deciding bool parameters are either (1) all positional parameters, and the first 3 of the 25 parameters, or (2) all keyword arguments, then this doable via a refactoring of the signature into a dedicated type. In other situations you're out of luck. If you're able to give an accurate representation of the 25-parameter-long signature and indicate which 3 parameters change the return type, someone might come up with a solution.

I don't wan't a solution to my real world problem, instead I deliberatly created a minimal example here, so other people can easily benefit from answers as well.
Hence I deleted the reference to the above-mentioned real world problem.

I would do this with a typed version of kwargs - this allows you to share the parameters between all overloads while only updating them in one place (Parameters). Unpack combined with a TypedDict allows us to do this:
from typing import Literal, TypedDict, Unpack, overload

class Parameters(TypedDict):
    var1: str
    var2: float
    var3: int

@overload
def test(switch: Literal[True], **kwargs: Unpack[Parameters]) -> int: ...
@overload
def test(switch: Literal[False], **kwargs: Unpack[Parameters]) -> None: ...

def test(switch: bool, **kwargs: Unpack[Parameters]) -> int | None:
    return 123 if switch is True else None

test_int: int = test(True, var1="test", var2=1.2,var3=2)
test_none: None = test(False, var1="test", var2=1.2,var3=2)

Alternatively, you could pack all the parameters into a separate object, which you may find easier to work with:
from typing import Literal, overload
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parameters:
    var1: str
    var2: float
    var3: int

@overload
def test(switch: Literal[True], params: Parameters) -> int: ...
@overload
def test(switch: Literal[False], params: Parameters) -> None: ...

def test(switch: bool, params: Parameters) -> int | None:
    return 123 if switch is True else None

test_int: int = test(True,Parameters(var1="test", var2=1.2,var3=2))
test_none: None = test(False, Parameters(var1="test", var2=1.2,var3=2))

Hope this helps!
